# Identify all continuous networks in a dataset

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, pgrouting, network-analyst, network

I have a set of pedestrian streets for a city. I would like to assign all of the streets that can be reached to one another along a continuous network to a unique group. I am wondering if there’s an off the shelf method (QGIS, ArcGIS, PgRouting) that can do this.

I have an image of roughly what I would like to accomplish. Basically, I have a set of roads on an “island” that are broken up barriers that make walking impossible (Interstates, Rivers, etc.).  I want the continuous part of each network to be assigned to its own group. For reference, I am trying to create "T-Communities" described in *Grannis, Rick. "T‐Communities: Pedestrian Street Networks and Residential Segregation in Chicago, Los Angeles, and New York." City & Community 4.3 (2005): 295-321.*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this workflow in Arc.:

1. Buffer road lines by a trivial distance (e.g. 1 Foot)
2. Select the “Dissolve All” options in Arc to merge all overlapping road buffers.
3. Convert multi-part to single part.
4. Convert feature to line.
5. Collapse dual lines to center lines.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for what is called the "[strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)" in graph theory jargon.

These network islands can be computed in QGIS with the grass plugin - See [v.net.components](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/v.net.components.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response. This solution worked in places my network was completely closed but failed in instances where the roads were not closed (e.g. the image). I posted a simple workflow that ended up giving me the results I wanted.